# Efficient conversion of boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 to std::string?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

**Problem**

I have a vector containing `cpp_dec_float_100` values from the `boost::multiprecision` library (i.e., an `std::vector<cpp_dec_float_100>`). My goal is to convert this to an `std::vector<std::string>` (i.e., to convert `cpp_dec_float_100` types to `string`s).

**What I've Tried**

- `boost::exception::to_string()` / `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>`: Boost provides some built-in tools for converting Boost types to `std::string`. Unfortunately, doing so on `cpp_dec_float` comes at a cost in precision, which is not sufficient for my purposes. For example, `1545596569.76676355` becomes `1.5456e+09`. If I were, for example, to write this to a file using `ostream`, I'd retain full precision.
- The `std::stringstream` approach: Boost's own documentation says:

> For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting
> need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of
> lexical_cast, the conventional std::stringstream approach is
> recommended.

I.e., this:

```
      // std::vector<cpp_dec_float_100> my_vector
      // contains my data set

      std::ostringstream ss;
      std::vector<std::string> my_vector_of_string;

      for(int i = 0; i < my_vector.size()-1; ++i){
        ss << setprecision(n) << my_vector[i];
        my_vector_of_string.push_back(ss.str());
      }
```

This works (and, not exactly surprisingly, gives the same precision I get with writing to a file). However (again, not exactly surprisingly), this is incredibly slow (in fact, impractically so my purposes) slow. My data set includes on the order of tens to hundreds of millions of elements.

---

Is there a more efficient method for converting a `cpp_dec_float_100` to `std::string`? My concern is purely the time taken to do so.

Please, let me know if there are any questions or if I've left anything important out. I'm not terribly familiar with Boost or `c++`.

Comment: Consider libfmt, boost karma, or indeed `stringstream`, but optimized by reuse.

Comment: I'm quite confused what the real task is. I cannot imagine a real-world use case where you'd need to decimally format  10'000'000+ numbers but NOT to a file, but a ... vector of strings?

Comment: In fact, if you can share a sef-contained program to optimize, I will optimize it for you. But make sure the sample matches your required use-case, otherwise it's a waste of time

Comment: @sehe Thanks for the suggestions, and the offer! Yes, this is an unusual situation. I'm essentially interfacing between a function which necessarily outputs a `vector` of `cpp_dec_float_100`, and a function which writes data in a proprietary file format and must be passed a `vector` of `string`. I'll try your suggestions, and put together a self-contained program.

Comment: Sounds like the proprietary file format writing (interface) is the real problem. Seems that the biggest win would be to avoid allocating the vector of strings. If you have that code i can probably does that as well.